# Log4Net Instances out of control

Tags: c#, log4net

Preface: I'm been looking up Log4Net questions for a while now, but have yet to really see one that gives me a clue as to why my particular issue is happening.  If any of you know an existing question/answer I can look at, feel free to point me in that direction.

My issue:  We use Log4Net across dozens of solutions at my employer.  A while back, I created a Common dll that included lots of reusable functions we use across all our C# Windows Applications. (so several different applications currently use this same dll) We are currently developing a large system, that currently performs a lot of info logging, and after this application running for less than 10 minutes, it runs my development machine out of memory.  Upon further examination, log4net.Core.StackFrameItem, log4net.Core.MethodItem, log4net.Core.LocationInfo, and log4net.Core.LoggingEvent have basically spun out of control in the application.  The memory usage exponentially goes up the longer the app runs.  It would seem that for every logging event, it is instantiating a new instance of log4net, and I currently cannot see why in code.  (after 3 minutes of running, 66,932 instances of StackFrameItem and MethodItem each exist)

Logging setup:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static void Setup(string callingAssembly)
    {
        var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        var patternLayout =
            new PatternLayout {ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] - %message%newline"};
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);

        var roller = new RollingFileAppender
        {
            AppendToFile = true,
            File = $"{path}\\SMS Logs\\{callingAssembly}.txt",
            Layout = patternLayout,
            MaxSizeRollBackups = 1,
            MaximumFileSize = "10MB",
            RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
            StaticLogFileName = true
        };
        roller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

        var memory = new MemoryAppender();
        memory.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }
}
```

Logger:

```
public class AppLog
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public static void LogInfo(string logMsg)
    {

        if (log.IsInfoEnabled)
        {
            log.Info(logMsg);
        }

    } // LogInfo

    public static void LogException(string logMsg, Exception ex)
    {

        if (log.IsFatalEnabled)
        {
            log.Fatal(logMsg);
            LogExceptionDetails(ex);
        }

    } // LogException
    private static void LogExceptionDetails(Exception ex, bool doStackTrace = true)
    {

        log.Fatal(ex.Message);

        if (doStackTrace)
        {
            log.Fatal(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            LogExceptionDetails(ex.InnerException, false);
        }

    } // LogException
    public static void LogDebug(string logMsg)
    {

        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            log.Debug(logMsg);
        }

    } // LogDebug


// ...etc... and all the other types of logging
```

Calling AppLog from anywhere:

```
if (Globals.DebugLogging)
            AppLog.LogDebug($"GetNetworkList: {url}");
```

If anybody sees how or why log4net would be creating exponential instances, please let me know.

Comment: What do you thing `MemoryAppender` is doing?

Comment: Where is your `LogManager.GetLogger` method?

Comment: I haven't used MemoryAppender ever but according to docs it says "The memory appender stores all the logging events that are appended in an in-memory array. " so it may be appending infinite number of logging events until memory is completely filled up. I'd try removing the `MemoryAppender` and check if memory usage is better.

Comment: Once I moved to Microsoft DI + NLog and felt like been born again, now they are my best friends in every app I work on.

Comment: So if I don't want to look at in-memory logging, I can comment out the MemoryAppender code, apparently.  Once I commented out MemoryAppender, my app now has a small memory footprint, and logging still works fine.  Thank you @basar bringing that up

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue, is to NOT add a MemoryAppender unless you really intend on looking at logging in-memory.  Once I removed the MemoryAppender, log4net consumed practically no Memory Usage report in Visual Studio.  (Thank you basar for mentioning MemoryAppender and how it works)